# Add features above X-axis or at the top of the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph that looks like:

[image]

Now I want to add some additional informations slightly above the X-axis based on two X-coordinates.

For example connect the values 1376 and 1837 and annotate them that it looks like (I know it looks crappy but just that you get an idea. And of course the place of the text is not ideal):

[image]

And there will be several regions which can be overlapping. I tried to do it with the `plt.arrow(1376, 0, 1837, 0)` but the arrow is not stopping at 1837. It is going on to the end of the X-axis. I also tried it with the basic text annotation tool but I never got what I want. The other solution would be to add the information on the top of the graph below the headline. So any of your Ideas regarding top or bottom can be helpful.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to indicate genome regions, i.e. a range of x values, or do you want to indicate pairs of specific x values?

Comment: I want to Indicate Genome Regions.

Comment: Also, your arrow doesn't work because the call signature is `plt.arrow(x,y,dx,dy)`. You need something like `plt.arrow(1376, 0, 1837-1376, 0)`. I would just plot a line, though.

Comment: Thanks, for the Info. I' am not that much into Python so I was pretty happy with getting the plot so far. I will look up how to plot a line.

Comment: Another possible visualization could be to use something like `plt.axhspan(1376, 1837, alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Yeah, I thought about that, too, but it will look ugly if there are a bunch of overlapping regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, though this is a bit of a manual process and not ideal (may be a bit tedious if you have lots of these) is to simply plot an extra line on the figure. You can specify the x coordinates between which you want to plot the line, and the y coordinates will be the vertical position on the graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some data
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

ax.plot([2,4],[-1,-1], color="red", lw=1) # add the line
ax.annotate('Test 1', xy=(2.5, -0.95)) # add text above the line

# increase the thickness of the line using lw =
ax.plot([6,8],[-1,-1], color="red", lw=3)
ax.annotate('Test 2', xy=(6.5, -0.95)) 

plt.show()
```

Which results in a figure like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending how many of these plots you need to make, you might want to automate the process for a list of regions/intervals. The problem, then, of course, is how to deal with overlapping intervals. The code below is an attempt to automate the process while resolving interval overlaps.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain, combinations

def annotate_intervals(intervals, labels, y0=0, dy=-1, ax=None):
    """
    Annotates an interval with a bar and a centred label below.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    intervals - (N, 2) array
        list of intervals
    labels - (N, ) iterable of strings
        list of corresponding labels
    y0 - int/float (default 0)
        baseline y value of annotations
    dy - int/float (default -1)
        shift in y to avoid overlaps of annotations
    ax - matplotlib axis object (default plt.gca())
        axis to annotate
    """

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # assign y values to each interval; resolve overlaps
    y = y0 + _get_levels(intervals) * dy

    for (start, stop), yy, label in zip(intervals, y, labels):
        ax.plot([start, stop], [yy, yy], lw=3)
        ax.text(start + (stop-start)/2., yy, label,
                horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom')

def _get_levels(intervals):
    """
    Assign a 'level' to each interval such that no two overlapping intervals are on the same level.
    Fill lower levels as much as possible before creating a new level.
    """

    # initialise output
    n = len(intervals)
    levels = np.zeros((n))

    # resolve overlaps
    overlaps = _get_overlaps(intervals)
    if np.any(overlaps):
        contains_overlaps, = np.where(np.any(overlaps, axis=0))
        remaining = list(contains_overlaps)
        ctr = 0
        while len(remaining) > 0:
            indices = _get_longest_non_overlapping_set(intervals[remaining])
            longest = [remaining.pop(ii) for ii in indices[::-1]]
            levels[longest] = ctr
            ctr += 1

    return levels

def _get_overlaps(intervals):
    """
    Arguments:
    ----------
    intervals - (N, 2) array
        list of intervals

    Returns:
    --------
    overlap - (N, N) array
        type of overlap (if any)

    overlap[ii,jj] = 0 - no overlap
    overlap[ii,jj] = 1 - start of interval[jj] within interval[ii]
    overlap[ii,jj] = 2 - stop  of interval[jj] within interval[ii]
    overlap[ii,jj] = 3 - interval[jj] encapsulated by interval[ii]
    overlap[ii,jj] = 4 - interval[jj] encapsulates interval[ii]

    """

    n = len(intervals)
    overlap = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.int)
    for ii, (start, stop) in enumerate(intervals):
        for jj, (s, t) in enumerate(intervals):
            if ii != jj:
                overlap[ii,jj] += int((s >= start) and (s < stop))
                overlap[ii,jj] += 2 * int((t >= start) and (t < stop))

    # if interval[jj] encapsulates interval[ii], overlaps[ii,jj] is still 0
    mask = overlap == 3
    overlap[mask.T] += 4

    return overlap

def _get_longest_non_overlapping_set(intervals):
    """
    Brute-force approach:
    1) Get all possible sets of intervals.
    2) Filter for non-overlapping sets.
    3) Determine total length of intervals for each.
    4) Select set with highest total.
    """
    indices = np.arange(len(intervals))
    lengths = np.diff(intervals, axis=1)
    powerset = list(_get_powerset(indices))
    powerset = powerset[1:] # exclude empty set

    total_lengths = np.zeros((len(powerset)))
    for ii, selection in enumerate(powerset):
        selection = np.array(selection)
        if not np.any(_get_overlaps(intervals[selection])):
            total_lengths[ii] = np.sum(lengths[selection])

    return powerset[np.argmax(total_lengths)]

def _get_powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)  # allows duplicate elements
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def test():
    import string
    n = 6
    intervals = np.sort(np.random.rand(n, 2), axis=1)
    labels = [letter for letter in string.ascii_lowercase[:n]]
    annotate_intervals(intervals, labels)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Luckily I''am just needing three plots at the moment. So doing it manually is not that hard. But maybe for the future your code could be really helpful :)